# pivothigh/pivotlow not working as expected

Tags: pine-script

Why is this code showing me wrong pivothighs it there are any? It is counting every second bar to the left and to the right not only one... If I change if to:

`bar_index % 1 == 0`, it is working right .

**Here my code :**

```
//@version=4
study("fckn test", overlay=true) 

if bar_index % 2 == 0
    ph = pivothigh(1,1)

    label.new(bar_index-1, low, tostring(ph))
```

Answer (score 1):

Not too sure what you are trying to do. Perhaps this?

```
//@version=4
study("fckn test", overlay=true)
pivotLegs = 1
// Find pivot outside `if` block because needs to run on every bar.
ph = pivothigh(pivotLegs, pivotLegs)
// Detect a new pivot.
newPh = not na(ph)
// If a new pivot is found, save the bar index where it was found.
bh = newPh ? bar_index - pivotLegs : na
if bar_index % 2 == 0 and not na(ph)
    label.new(bh, high[pivotLegs], tostring(ph))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank You for answer. Why cant I use function pivothigh() under the IF statement? Because if I use it under the IF statement it will produce unexpected results. For example, I want to filter some patterns, for example three green candles and then if it is true I want to find pivothigh.

Comment: You're welcome. Many functions requiring execution on every bar will not work correctly in `if` blocks. See [Why do some functions and built-ins evaluate incorrectly in if or ternary (?) blocks?](https://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/#why-do-some-functions-and-built-ins-evaluate-incorrectly-in-if-or-ternary--blocks).